# I don't know how to capitalize this string, while keeping the finding function of the code

Tags: python

Basically it is supposed to search a txt file for a string and capitalize it. I have gotten this far with some help from stack overflow but anything I try doesn't work.

```
import os, fileinput
import sys, subprocess

prompt = "> "

print("text to search for: ")
string1 = input(prompt)

with open(os.path.expanduser("/users/acarroll55277/documents/notes/new_myfile.txt"), 'r+') as f:

    matches = list()
    [matches.append(i) for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()) if string1 in line.strip()]
    f.write(f.replace(string1, string1.capitalize))

    if len(matches) == 0: print(f"string {string1} not found")

    [print(f"string {string1} found in line{i}") for i in matches]
```

and this is the error message I get

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: You need to call replace on a string, not on a file.

Answer (score 1):

you had some redundant function calls, and some errors such as not using `()` on capitalize and calling `replace` on a file object instead of on a string.

try this:

```
import os, fileinput
import sys, subprocess

prompt = "> "

print("text to search for: ")
string1 = input(prompt)

with open(os.path.expanduser("/users/acarroll55277/documents/notes/new_myfile.txt"), 'r+') as f:

    matches = [line.replace(string1,string1.capitalize()) for line.strip() in f.readlines() if string1 in line]
    f.writelines(matches)

    if len(matches) == 0: print(f"string {string1} not found")

    for i in matches:
        print(f"string {string1} found in line{i}")
```